# Mongoose Populate and Search by Array of References

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Mongoose Populate syntax and structure. I have two schemas. The **Parent** has an array of **Child** references.

```
const Parent = new Schema({
  name: String,
  children: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Child'}]
});

const Child = new Schema({
  name: String
});
```

To populate the **Parent** I've been doing this:

```
Parent
  .findById(parent.id)
  .populate('children')
    .exec( (err, parent) => {
      parent.children = arrayOfInsertedChildDocs;
      parent.save();
    });
```

The Parent references save, but is there a way to query for **Parents** that have a reference to a certain **Child**? For example all Parents that have a reference to a child with the Id of *ObjectId('xxxxxxxxx')* in their children array?

This is what I've been trying but it's not working.

```
let query = { "children._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(childId) };

Parent.find(query, (err, parents) => {
   //process parents 
})
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The query to get the **Parent** from a child id in the nested array is:

```
Parent
  .find({"children":ObjectId(child.id)})
  .populate("children")
  .exec((err,parents) => {
    //process parents
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to search for element in MongoDB array set. Suppose you have a document.

```
{
  name :"harry",
  childen:["10ahhdj20","9ajskjakj9","8aiisu38","2jjaksjah0"]
}
```

So for searching inside an array list, you can use this.

```
db.parents.find( { tags: { $all: [ "10ahhdj20", "812922dd" ] } } )
```

You will get all the parents who have these children.